# How to create a CSS animation

Tags: css, easing, css-animations

So I want this div to go from `margin-left:900px` to `550px` in a smooth animation where it starts fast and goes slower and slower in a smooth kind of way. This should happen on page load.

I tried with javascript, but couldn't figure it out...

I know you can do something like this with CSS3, but how? Could anyone give me a code example? Tried Googling but couldn't find the answer...

Lets say I have a div with an id:

```
<div id='slide'>
```

and the CSS:

```
#slide {
  width: 200px;
  height 200px;
  margin-left: 900px;
  background-color: #435;
}
```

How do I animate this?

Comment: Have you looked on Google or SO at all?

Comment: As I clearly wrote: "Tried google but couldn't find the answer...", then yes!

Comment: @user3144630 Please provide what you have tried so far

Comment: Sorry, you wrote that after I asked.

Comment: Oh, ok... sorry I went rude ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it using a CSS animation on load without javascript interaction, you need to use a [keyframe animation](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/)

```
#slide {
  width: 200px;
  height 200px;
  margin-left: 900px;
  background-color: #435;
  -webkit-animation: slide 1s ease-out forwards;
  animation: slide 1s ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes slide {
    100% {
        margin-left:500px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% {
        margin-left:500px;
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6TFHR/1/)

`forwards` makes it stay in the 100% keyframe state, `slide` is the animation name, `ease-out` makes it slow down as the animation goes on (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) for a full list and [here](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/) or [here](http://cubic-bezier.com/#0,.72,.2,1.11) to generate your own), and `1s` is the animation duration, in this case it is 1 second.

Other notes:

- At this point in time the the animations have to be browser prefixed
  in most cases
- If you wished, you could include a 0% keyframe with the default
  `margin-left:900px`, but it is not necessary in this case because it 
  is declared in the `#slide` CSS
- You can use as many keyframes as you would like ranging from 0% to 100%
  including decimal formats, e.g. `50.001% { ...`
- Another form you can write it in is using `from { ...` and `to { ...`
  where `from` = `0%` and `to` = `100%`

Comment: Doens't do anything...

Comment: I'd consider this overkill for such a task. keyframes aren't needed.

Comment: @user3144630 yes it does but the margin-left is 900 which is to big to view in the fiddle

Comment: @Josiah How else do you suggest having the animation apply on page load? You could with javascript but that'd take more processing than an animation I'd assume

Comment: @ZachSaucier, I'd personally do it the way my answer describes. Using the transition property, setting the new margin-left value via JS. I find keyframes to be extremely messy personally.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `transition` property. E.G.

`transition: margin-left 1s ease-out`

ease-out will give the effect you want. (Starts fast and gets slower)

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pM6cx/3/

Just change the marginLeft property in your onLoad function similar to the fiddle if you want to achieve this effect on window load.

Keyframes aren't needed for such a task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you using CSS3 keyframes:

```
    #box{
    position:relative;
    top: 100px; 
    left:100px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation: move 5s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move{
    0% {top: 100px; left: 100px;} 
    100% {top: 100px; left: 500px;} 
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/En4jk/1/)

**EDIT**

By adding the `forwards` property after `ease-in-out`:

```
 -webkit-animation: move 5s ease-in-out forwards;
```

[**Updated FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/En4jk/2/)

This means the animation will apply the property values for the time the animation ended

Comment: It works! :D Thank you... But I still have problem.. when the animation ends, it goes back to 900 px...?

Comment: @user3144630 just add "forward" after ease-in-out :) Consider upvoting and check as right answer ;)

Comment: i tied, but can you post how to write it? :p

Comment: @Nilzone- Try to make your examples share the same code in the question. This isn't using `margin-left` nor the same HTML, it looks like a copy and paste from something else

Comment: @ZachSaucier I agree I should've made my example based on his code, but I assure you, it's not copy-pasted from anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

To change the speed of a CSS animation, you could use the `animation-timing-function` :)

the trick is finding the right function.
e.g:

```
animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0,.72,.51,1);
```

You can use

http://cubic-bezier.com/#0,.72,.51,1

http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/54hvZ/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `css transition`:

```
#slide:hover{transition:all 0.2s ease;width:400px;}
```

[Knee's JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaptKnee/yPg4H/)